# Java Regex to Flutter Regex

Tags: java, regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a Java regex to a Flutter(Dart) regex but I am having trouble.

My Java Code and Regex example, witch returns Matching:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String EMAIL_VALIDATION_REGEX = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$";
    String email = "testemail@gmail.com";
    if(!Pattern.matches(EMAIL_VALIDATION_REGEX, email)) {
        System.out.println("Not matching!");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Matching!");
    }
}
```

My Flutter Code example witch returns Not Matching:

```
    final RegExp _emailRegex = RegExp(
    r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$",
    caseSensitive: false,
    multiLine: false);

final String _email = "testemail@gmail.com";

if (!_emailRegex.hasMatch(_email)) {
  print("Not Matching!");
} else {
  print("Matching!");
}
```

I have basically copied the regex that i use in java and added r as a prefix. Can someone help me identify the issue with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `r` prefix creates a raw String.
As a result you don't need to double escape your `\\.` sequence. Use a single backslash: `\.`

See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

> Note the use of a raw string (a string prefixed with r) in the example
> above. Use a raw string to treat each character in a string as a
> literal character.

And https://www.learndartprogramming.com/fundamentals/strings-and-raw-strings-in-dart/

> What is a raw strings in Dart: In Dart programming language, raw strings are a type of strings where special characters such as \ do not get special treatment.

> Raw strings are useful when you want to define a String that has a lot of special characters.

> Raw strings are also useful when you are defining complex regular expressions that otherwise are difficlut to define using the single and double quotes.

The main advantage of using a raw String with regular expressions is that, unlike in Java, you can copy and paste your regex and test it easily in other tools, such as https://www.regexr.com, without worrying about additional escaping.